# Racket - Add or remove element from a 2dlist

Tags: racket

I'm doing a problem which asks me to write a function that consumes a
list (dict1) and a list (act) that contains an action (remove or add) and a value. The updates should adhere to the following specifications:

• If the first element of act is “remove" and the key is in the dictionary, then the matching value in the associated list should be removed.

• If the matching value happens to be the last element in the associated list, then the key should remain in the dictionary, but the associated list becomes empty. If the value is not in the dictionary, the dictionary does not change.

• If the value of act is "add" and the key is in the dictionary, then the new value
should be added to the associated list in the dictionary if it does not already exist. If the value already exists in the associated list, the updated dictionary would not change.

• If the value of act is “add" and the key does not exist in the dictionary, then a
new association list entry for the key should be added to the dictionary.

For example:

```
(define dict1 (list (list "Num" (list 5 1.3 -1))
 (list "Char" (list #\p))
 (list "Str"
 (list "cs" "CS" "Computer Science"))))
```

Then

```
(update dict1 (list "add" true)) =>
(list (list "Num" (list 5 1.3 -1))
      (list "Bool" (list true))
      (list "Char" (list #\p))
      (list "Str" (list "cs" "CS" "Computer Science")))

(update dict1 (list "remove" "cs")) =>
(list (list "Num" (list 5 1.3 -1))
      (list "Char" (list #\p))
      (list "Str" (list "CS" "Computer Science")))
```

I could only come up with the first step, below is what I have so far:

```
(define (update dict1 act)
  (cond
    [(equal? (first act) "remove") (remove-value dict1 (second act))]
    [(equal? (first act) "add") (add-value dict1 (second act))]))
```

For this question I'm only allowed to use `member?` or `remove`.
I knew that I've been asking a lot of questions in the past couple of days, but I am new to racket and I am doing my best to learn it :( Please help

Answer (score 0):

**no set! no local version**

```
; please tell us which language you use (in front of code)

#|

In Beginning Student Language variabe can't be function
error: function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a variable

(define (f fn) (fn 1))
(f add1)
|#
; use "Advanced Student" language or "#lang racket".
#lang racket

(define dict1
  (list (list "Num" (list 1 2 3))
        (list "Char" (list #\p))
        (list "Bool" '())
        (list "Str" (list "a" "b" "c"))))

(define (index-title action)
  (cond
    [(number? (second action)) 0]
    [(char? (second action)) 1]
    [(boolean? (second action)) 2]
    [(string? (second action)) 3]
    [else (error "type error")]))


(define (my-remove word lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(equal? word (first lst))
     (rest lst)]
    [else
     (cons (first lst)
           (my-remove word (rest lst)))]))


(define (exist? word lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) #f]
    [(equal? word (first lst)) #t]
    [else
     (exist? word (rest lst))]))

(define (add-if-not-exist word data)
  (if (exist? word data)
      data
      (cons word data)))

(define (action-to-data word data action)
  (cond
    [(equal? action "add")
     (add-if-not-exist word data)]
    [(equal? action "remove")
     (my-remove word data)]))


(define (aux-build-list i n dict act a-function)
  (cond
    [(= i n) empty]
    [else
     (cons (a-function i dict act)
           (aux-build-list (+ i 1) n dict act a-function))]))


(define (my-build-list n dict act a-function)
  (aux-build-list 0 n dict act a-function))


(define (build-new-sub-dict n dict act)
  (cond
    [(= n (index-title act))
     (list (first (list-ref dict n))
           (action-to-data (second act) (second (my-list-ref dict n)) (first act)))]
    [else
     (list-ref dict n)]))


(define (my-list-ref lst n)
  (cond
    [(< n 0) (error "error")]
    [(= n 0) (first lst)]
    [else
     (my-list-ref (rest lst) (- n 1))]))


(define (update dict act)
  (set! dict1
        (my-build-list (length dict)
                       dict
                       act
                       (lambda (n dict act) (build-new-sub-dict n dict act)))))

;;; Test
(update dict1 '("add" 2))
(update dict1 '("remove" 3))
(update dict1 '("add" 4))
(update dict1 '("add" 4))
(update dict1 '("remove" 1))
(update dict1 '("remove" 2))
dict1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I'm not allowed to use lambda or filter or the built-in functions in this line : ```(begin (set! dict1 (build-list 4 build-new-sub-dict)) dict1)``` ; could you explain those to me and maybe modify those ? Thank you :P

Comment: When I run the program it says ```local``` is not defined in beginning student language :( How should I change that so it can work in BSL?

Comment: @Sillage I just update answer with no local version.

Comment: When it runs ```cons (a-function i dict act) ... ```n```(aux-build-list)``` there is an error message: function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a variable. I don't know why that happens